# How to load a .NET Core assembly from an application written in .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, reflection, .net-core

We have an application written in .NET which browses .NET assemblies using Reflection API. When we use this application to browse `dll` compiled with .NET Core 2.0, it fails with following exception. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.NewMethod() in c:\Users\faisal_iqbal\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\CoreX\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 23
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\faisal_iqbal\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\CoreX\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 16
```

Comment: Are you using `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad()`?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I have tried using that either. But the point is that it fails to load System.Runtime.dll

Comment: .NETCore is a very different framework.  If you build that assembly by targeting .NETStandard 2.0 instead and target your app to at least 4.6.1 then you can do this.

Comment: @HansPassant but how do tools like Reflector and dnspy manage to browse assemblies irrespective of their target framework?

Comment: Reflector does not use reflection, it uses the low-level metadata interfaces.  IMetaDataAssemblyImport and friends.  The metadata format is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question.

> > NETCore is a very different framework. If you build that assembly by
> >     targeting .NETStandard 2.0 instead and target your app to at least
> >     4.6.1 then you can do this.
>
> – Hans Passant

Since both .NET Framework and .NET Core are different frameworks, each has its own `Reflection API`.

If you need to load assemblies merely for meta data reading purpose, use [Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) framework which works for both .NET Framework as well as for .NET Core. It doesn't load the assembly or dependent assemblies as Reflection does. It simply reads the meta data information like

- Types in assembly
- Properties, fields and methods in a type
- Name, FullName and Namespace of a type
- etc...

Comment: These are actually two answers. Although the comment by Hans Passant is highlighted, I would like to point out that the reference to Mono.Cecil helped me in this case.